# Storyboard localization with UIPageviewController

Tags: ios, swift, localization, storyboard, uipageviewcontroller

I can't seem to get a `UIPageViewController` to work with localization.

I'm creating the `UIPageController` and its children programmatically:

```
class HomeTutorialVC: UIPageViewController {

    var closeTutorial: UIBarButtonItem? = nil
    var navigationDelegate: ControllerPresentedListener? = nil
    var pageControl: UIPageControl!

    lazy var orderedChildren: [UIViewController] = {
       return [
            self.controllerWithIdentifier(withStoryboardIdentifier: "tutorialPage1"),
            self.controllerWithIdentifier(withStoryboardIdentifier: "tutorialPage2"),
            self.controllerWithIdentifier(withStoryboardIdentifier: "tutorialPage3"),
            self.controllerWithIdentifier(withStoryboardIdentifier: "tutorialPage4"),
            self.controllerWithIdentifier(withStoryboardIdentifier: "tutorialPage5"),
            self.controllerWithIdentifier(withStoryboardIdentifier: "tutorialPage6")
        ]
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupNavigation()
        setupView()
        setupPageController() .   // This setup the page controller datasource, delegate, firstController and an optional pageControl
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

`controllerWithIdentifier` is grabbing a controller in the storyboard based on its id:

```
extension HomeTutorialVC {
    func controllerWithIdentifier(withStoryboardIdentifier identifier: String) -> UIViewController {
        return UIStoryboard(name: "Tutorial", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier)
    }
}
```

All this code works well, and my storyboard is localized for multiple languages. While most of my views are being localized correctly, the page controller's children are not (it always matches the base language), any idea why?

Here's the storyboard with the 6 controllers identified by their ids:

[image]

and a sample of the localization for one of the child controller:

**Tutorial.strings (English)**

```
/* Class = "UITextView"; text = "That's it! Be creative and productive!"; ObjectID = "EhQ-Lx-EwA"; */
"EhQ-Lx-EwA.text" = "That's it! Be creative and productive!";
```

**Tutorial.strings (French)**

```
/* Class = "UITextView"; text = "That's it! Be creative and productive!"; ObjectID = "EhQ-Lx-EwA"; */
"EhQ-Lx-EwA.text" = "C'est tout! Soyez créati(f/ve) et producti(f/ve)!";
```

#### Notes:

I also tried to replace all content in the french version of the localization file by "Test" (As I though it could eventually be a special character breaking the file, but it didn't solve the issue).

Comment: where are you udating pageControl?

Comment: you need to update the UIPageController, check your delegates to tell which new controller it will show after page controller swipe, you can check this file if want https://github.com/Iraniya/Infinite-Scrollable-TabBarController/blob/master/InfiniteScrollableTabBarController/PageViewController.swift

Comment: Thanks for your reply @IraniyaNaynesh, both `pageControl` and `delegates` have been implemented, I just didn't add them here as I though they were not relevant.

As I mentioned in the post, the PageViewController works as expected: it presents 6 pages corresponding to the controllers with the ids tutorialPage1...6.

Navigation buttons on the PageViewController in the storyboard will get localized correctly while the textview specific to each child controller won't.